# Making https request with fetch in react native

Tags: react-native, fetch, info.plist

**Background**

All over the internet people are asking why they cant make http request in react native. The answer is commonly because they must update their exceptions in the `info.plist`. For me this was an issue at one point at time. I updated my settings and `http` in a `fetch` request was working.

Since than I updated my server and have `SSL` on my node api end points. When I hit the end points in post man on the production server there are no problems. But when I remove the settings I added to the `info.plist` to allow `http` request and then try to run my app I get the error again when running code that hits the end points using `https` in the fetch call.

**Code Example**

I updated my code to make the request like this:

```
fetch('https://api.email.com/v1/clients/update', {
...
}
```

When making request with http like this:

```
fetch('http://api.email.com/v1/clients/update', {
    ...
    }
```

I used this in the `info.plist`

```
<key>api.wuno.com</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
<key>wuno.com</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

But now I once again get the error:

> Network Request Failed

**Question**

Now that I have `SSL` on the `API` end points. It is working when hit with postman. I removed the exceptions from `info.plist`. 
What steps do I need to take to make `https` work with `fetch` for my `react native` app?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Actually I have not went back to this specific app and worked on it again. So no I have not figured it out. But in this case I was using NGINX on an Apache server. I think it might have to do with me not setting up the SSL correctly on the NGINX server since this API is a node application, not a PHP application.